# Filament refresh action button as well when triggering an action

Tags: php, laravel, filamentphp

I'm using filamentphp to hack together a small tool for internal use.
I'm trying to add an action to a Person model to toggle is_approved boolean, and it works fine but I can't figure out how to refresh the action button itself on trigger, other than full page reload.

[Filamentphp docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/pages#refreshing-form-data) describe how to refresh form data on trigger, but not the action button itself.

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\PersonResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\PersonResource;
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;

class EditPerson extends EditRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = PersonResource::class;

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            Action::make($this->record->is_approved ? 'Disapprove' : 'Approve')
                ->color($this->record->is_approved ? 'danger' : 'success')
                ->action(function () {
                    $this->record->is_approved = !$this->record->is_approved;
                    $this->record->save();
                    $this->refreshFormData([
                        'is_approved',
                    ]);
                    Notification::make()
                        ->title($this->record->is_approved ? 'Approved successfully' : 'Disapproved successfully')
                        ->success()
                        ->send();
                    $this->redirect('edit');
                })
        ];
    }
}
```

Commenting out `$this->redirect('edit');` will still flip the boolean, but action button will not update.

This is just bare minimum to get it working, albeit in a very crude way. However there is a glaring issue where if you change form input and than decide to Approve/Disapprove before saving you would lose form changes - which is different from the rest of the app and bad UX.

Am approaching the whole thing in a sensible way? I'm not much of a programmer, just hacking things together with variables, functions and loops.

I went trough filamentphp docs to try and find a "native" way of doing something like this, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across same issue. You can use `redirect` as following:

```php
Action::make('RefreshOrder')
        ->icon('heroicon-m-paper-airplane')
        ->requiresConfirmation()
        ->action(function (Orders $record) {
            // Redirect page to any url you want
            redirect(static::getUrl('view', ['record' => $record->id,]));
        }
})
```

Assuming that you have `getPages` defined in your resource:

```php
public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListOrder::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateOrder::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditOrder::route('/{record}/edit'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewOrder::route('/{record}'),
        ];
    }
```

I am using `view` to open up View page. Depend what you need. You can set any URL to   `redirect('https://....')`.